Is there a good way to run selenium tests on a Linux machine against a WebKit browser?
A majority of our users are on mobile safari, but we run our automation in pipelines using a linux kernal.  Is there a way a good option for running our tests in webkit-based browser to ensure it renders correctly on Safari (or as best we can)? I've seen webkitgtk, and I did find some driver documentation on it, but I don't know anything about it AT ALL, other than it exists.
